World Position Offset from Realtime Virtual Texture when loading level
I have a grid of instanced meshes where I’m using an RVT with the landscape world height to feed into the material of the grid so it deforms to the landscape. Issue is, if I load into the level directly, it looks fine as pictured below:

But if I first start on another level, (eg. a main menu or so) and then load into that level, the grid doesn’t load correctly, it looks like below.

This is my configuration on the material for the grid instanced static mesh. It gets sent directly to the WPO.

Is there something I should be doing/Am doing incorrectly?
Thank you!
